# Optimize included files and uses in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

I try to increase performance of Delphi 2007 and Codeinsight.
In the application there are 483 files added in the DPR file.

I don't know if it is imagination but I feel that I got better performance from Codeinsight by simply readd all files in the DPR.

I also think (correct me if I'm wrong) that all files that are included in a uses section also should be included in the DPR file for best performance.

My question is, does it exists a tool that scan the whole project and give a list what files are missing in the DPR file and what files can be removed? Would also be nice to have a list of uses that can be removed in the PAS files.

I found Pascal Analyzer that seems to be a good tool. Comments about this specially in this case is appreciated.

A related question is [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934623/when-should-i-add-a-file-reference-to-a-delphi-project)

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the same editor as Pascal Analyser, **ICARUS** is free and do this job in the simplest way.

http://www.peganza.com/#ICARUS

Comment: I use the commercial version **Pascal Analyser** but it is often wrong, so I no longer bother about it.

Answer (score 6):

Regarding the unused units: [cnWizards](http://www.cnpack.org/index.php?lang=en) contains a uses cleaner which works very well